# How to make validation on date after adding the automatically slash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, date

I have a text field. If any user enters the date it will automatically add the slash on it but the issue is it also accepting the 60/60/6060.
It also accepts the character also. Would you help me out with validation in it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
            $("#txtDate").keyup(function(e){
                if (e.keyCode != 8){    
                    if ($(this).val().length == 2){
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                    }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                    }
                }
            });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="date"  placeholder="date (dd/mm/yy)" maxlength=10 id="txtDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkdate($mth,$day,$yr) or regex to validate the date.

```
/(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}/


$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtDate").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 8) {

                if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                } else if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                }

            }
        });

        //below will clear the textbox onblur if invalid date entered
        $("#txtDate").blur(function () {
            var reg = /(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}/;
            if (!reg.test($("#txtDate").val())) {
                // clear box if invalid
                $("#txtDate").val("");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but where should I use it

Comment: It resolved almost 90% issue. Just want to know. Can we set the $("#txtDate").html("Invalid date") instated of $("#txtDate").val("");It will be more clear to understand it.

Comment: yes, depend on your requirement you can set the value on the textbox or any label to show that validation message.